# Issues with displaying salesforce rich text editor image

Tags: salesforce, article, knowledge-management

We are having few rich text box in our custom objects in force.com enterprise edition. These rich text box are rendered in an android application given to our clients. Till now we were using the android app online but due to huge customer demand, we wish to make our app offline. But we are facing difficulties due to images in rich text box. The images in rich text box are stored as in a [form](https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a0B900000064u1S&feoid=00N90000004WTNB&refid=0EM9000000009Jg)

But when we try to use the android app offline, we cannot see the images in webview. Consulting our web developer, he said that the images do not have static path and so they cannot be downloaded and stored for offline use. So my query is, is there some way, which will help us to get static path for the images inserted in Rich Text Box available in force.com, so that we can use them offline.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago and also raised the issue with salesforce. They got back to me saying that images within rich text boxes could be stored in any server and needs to be authenticated to via a browser to have access too.

But you could try to use this, but its not a guaranteed approach as salesforce can change the way they store images.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/API-access-to-Knowledge-article-content-inline-images/td-p/233065

Hope this helps.

Here's the response from SFDC :

As discussed over the call, as of now Salesforce does not have this feature built in the current release, else we would be more than happy to help you.

However, you can also post an idea on our Idea Exchange, where our customers share their ideas and expectations. (http://sites.force.com/ideaexchange/ideaHome)

Please feel free to contact us, if you need any further assistance.

Thank you for contacting salesforce.
Regards

---

Developer Support Engineer
salesforce.com